# How to access Craft.EditableTable instance in CraftCM

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, garnish

I am developing a custom plugin that has a variable setting that can take multiple options. I've decided to use `forms.editableTable` from Craft's `_includes/forms`. It does the job great, saving and retrieving the settings.

Now I am trying to add validation to the columns on the table: the validation model is set and I am correctly passing the errors to the "right" position (*Meaning I get the row index and which column has the error*).

I know [Craft.EditableTable](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/2.6.2997/src/resources/js/craft/EditableTable.js) has the [getRowHtml](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/2.6.2997/src/resources/js/craft/EditableTable.js#L100) method that I can use to retrieve the row and apply error classes to the field(s).

I've watched the [Javascript in the Control Panel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=7&v=OcgdIlBlZc8) video, but Craft.EditableTable doesn't set a data attribute with it's instance.

Is there any other ways to get it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after fiddling with it for a while, this is what I came up with it:

When using `forms.editableTable` make sure you don't initialize `Craft.EditableTable`. You can do that by setting the `initJs` to `false`:

```
{{ forms.editableTable({
    id: 'myTableId',
    name: 'myTableName',
    cols: yourTableCols,
    ...
    initJs: false,
    ...
}) }}
```

That means that you will have to initialize the `Craft.EditableTable` yourself:

```
{% includejs %}
(function () {

  var t = new Craft.EditableTable(
    "{{ 'myTableId'   | namespaceInputId   | e('js') }}",
    "{{ 'myTableName' | namespaceInputName | e('js') }}",
    {{ yourTableCols|json_encode|raw }},
    {
      onAddRow: function( tr ) {
        // attach event listeners to row fields here
      }
    }
  );

} ());
{% endincludejs %}
```

From this point on, you can add your own listeners to the fields in the row.